# Or condition not working in FTL?

Tags: freemarker, or-operator

I'm trying to put a condition in free marker template but it's not working . here is the condidtion

```
<#if "${Model.Order.Addresses.DeliveryAddress}" != "TRED"  || "${Model.Order.Addresses.DeliveryAddress}" != "TREF">
            Please note that it can take some time for the  tracking.
    </#if>
```

Is there any syntax issue in this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's a logical problem there. Your condition says "the delivery address is not TRED or the delivery address is not TREF", which is true for all delivery addresses. I guess you want either "the delivery address is TRED or the delivery address is TREF", in which case use `==` instead of `!=`, or "the delivery address is not TRED *and* the delivery address is not TREF", in which case use `&&` instead of `||`.

As of the syntax, instead of `"${Model.Order.Addresses.DeliveryAddress}" != "TRED"` you should just write  `Model.Order.Addresses.DeliveryAddress != "TRED"`. It will give the same result as far as `DeliveryAddress` is a string, but is shorter.